# Array empty in a Non repeating algorithm for random numbers in Xcode with arc4random

Tags: xcode, algorithm, random, arc4random, non-repetitive

I've a problem with the generation of random values with arc4random in Xcode. I want to exclude from the random generation those number that are already picked up. This is the algorithm that I've wroten

```
int randomValue =  (arc4random() % numberofquest)+ 1;
int kk=1;

if (kk==1) {

//first time add the first random value
[oldquest addObject: randomValue];
    }
else {
        //control if the number is already in the vector
        for (int j=1; j<[oldquest count]; j++)
        {

            if (randomValue==oldquest[j])
            {

                randomValue =  (arc4random() % numerodomande)+ 1;
            }
            else
            {
                [oldquest addObject: randomValue];
            }
        }

}
kk=kk+1
```

But It doesn't work. I suppose maybe because randomvalue and the j-th object in the array are not comparable (int the first and string the second?). Can anyone help me please?

Comment: See http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/how-to-generate-a-list-of-unique-random-numbers for the general solutions.

Comment: Note that you should never % the result of `arc4random()`. It injects modulo bias. If you want a random number in a range, use `arc4random_uniform()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, Ares answer was almost right. You can compare two different NSNumber objects.

Here is my solution:

```
- (int) generateRandomNumber {
    int number = arc4random() % 100;

    if ([chosen_numbers indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number]]!=NSNotFound)
        number = [self generateRandomNumber];

    [chosen_numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number]];
    return number;
}
```

Since Alessandro has some trouble implementing it heres an example inside a UIViewController class. This works for 100 numbers:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController {
    NSMutableArray * chosen_numbers;    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    chosen_numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i<90; i++) {
        NSLog(@"number: %d",[self generateRandomNumber]);
    }
}

- (int) generateRandomNumber {
    int number = arc4random() % 100;

    if ([chosen_numbers indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number]]!=NSNotFound)
        number = [self generateRandomNumber];

    [chosen_numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number]];
    return number;
}

@end
```

Comment: how can I call this function and pass the value number to randomValue? TY

Comment: randomValue = [self generateRandomNumber];

Comment: chosen_numbers should be a NSMutableArray previously initialized.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. But if I try this method my app crashes when I touch from the main menu the new game, returning a BAD ACCESS MEMORY. Why?

Comment: This method generates 130913 random numbers before crash. But it never exit from the loop

Comment: The problem seems to be in the if statement and in the if/else cycle

Comment: Did you declare the chosen_numbers ivar outside this method? NSArray* chosen_numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: sure! but I've declared it in a Mutable Array. Why allocate a huge vector when the player can lose in 3 questions? In this case I could have a big computational cost.

Comment: I've wroten the code like this..but it doesn't work... Someone know why?    - (int) generateRandomNumber {
    int number = (arc4random() % numerodomande)+ 1;
    
    if ([oldquest indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number]]!=NSNotFound) {
        [oldquest addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number]];
        return number;
    }
    else {
        [self generateRandomNumber];
    }
    return -1;
}'

Comment: your code generate a bad acces memory, with an infinite number of randoms value without exiting from the function

Comment: initializing the vector as a NSmutableArray, the code works for 2 questions and after "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Value length must be greater than 0'"

Comment: I added some code showing a complete UIViewController class that just generates and prints those numbers. It works for 100 different numbers (between 0 and 100).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    -(void) generateRandomNumber {

        int randomValue =  arc4random_uniform(numberofquest) + 1;

        if([oldQuest indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomValue] == NSNotFound) {
            //Unique value
            [oldQuest addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomValue]];
        }
        else {
            //Value already exists. Look for another one
            return [self generateRandomNumber];

        }
    }
```

Obviously oldQuest is NSMutableArray instance that was previously initialized.

Comment: I think you are not puting the new number into the array.

Comment: He did not ask to put new numbers into the array, I am assuming he wants a function to return a unique random number.

Comment: If you don't put the numbers into the oldQuest array how do you know the new one is unique?

Anyway, I don't think your solution works, see my answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I need so save the number in the nsmutable array to prevent the question repeating! :)

Comment: @Odrakir - You are right. I've updated answer to add to add numbers to array.

Comment: Not quite right. If the number exists in the array you look for another one but never return anything. See my answer, I tested it and it works.

Comment: Here the randomvalue remains in the function, that's void.

Answer (score 1):

You are right - it doesn't work because here:

```
            if (randomValue==oldquest[j])
```

you are trying to compare an `int` with an object... NSArrays can only store objects. In fact this line should not work for that reason:

```
[oldquest addObject: randomValue];
```

You need to box the int as an NSNumber and store that in the array:

```
NSNumber* boxedRandomValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:randomValue];
[oldquest addObject: boxedRandomValue];
```

Then unbox it using the NSNumber instance method `-(int)intValue` before comparing values:

```
 if (randomValue==[oldquest[j] intValue])
```

*update*

There are a few other issues you will have to attend to:

- the value of kk is reset to 1 on each iteration of the test, so `kk == 1` is always true, the `else` clause is never invoked. You need to set it once only outside of this block of code (for example you could make it a property, set it to 1 on initialise, then access and increment it here). Better still, just use [oldquest count] instead: `if ([oldquest count]==0) {} else {}`. Then you can dispense with your `kk` counter altogether.
- your for-loop starts with j=1. This should be j=0 to address the first item in the array (item 0).

*update 2*

This line: `randomValue =  (arc4random() % numerodomande)+ 1` is going to cause all sort of other problems due to it's position in the checking loop. Try one of these suggestions:

- just `return` when you come across a dupe. No number gets added to the array...
- set a BOOL test inside the loop, deal with it outside:

  ```
  BOOL repeatedValue = NO;
  for (int j=0; j<[self.oldquest count]; j++){
      if (randomValue==[self.oldquest[j] intValue]) {
          repeatedValue = YES;
          break;
      }
  }
  if (repeatedValue){
      NSLog (@"value repeated");
      [self addRandom];  
      //recursive call to this code block, 
      //assuming it is a method called `addRandom`
  }
  ```
- Try a compact version of the last suggestion (similar to Odrakir's solution) - I've enclosed it in an `addRandom` method so  you can see how to call it recursively.

  ```
    - (void) addRandom {
      int numberofquest = 5;
      int randomValue =  (arc4random() % numberofquest)+ 1;
      NSNumber* boxedValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:randomValue];
      if ([self.oldquest indexOfObject:boxedValue]==NSNotFound) {
          [self.oldquest addObject: boxedValue];
      } else {
          [self addRandom];
      }
  }
  ```

  (If you do loop until you find a unique number you will have to watch out, as your total set of numbers is finitely limited to `numberofquest`, so when you have a full set you may end up with an infinite loop.)
- Instead of using NSMutableArray, you could use MutableOrderedSet instead - it's an ordered collection of *unique* objects, so will not add an object twice.

*in @interface*

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableOrderedSet setOfRandoms;
```

*in @implementation*

```
int randomValue =  (arc4random() % numberofquest)+ 1;
NSNumber randomValueBoxed = [NSNumber numberWithInt:randomValue];
[setOfRandoms addObject:randomValueBoxed];
```

*update 3*

The previous hints assumed it was the *list* of randoms you were interested in. Here is a complete solution to return a new unique random int in a self-contained method.

You need to set up 2 properties in your @interface *and initialise them somewhere*:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int maxRand;
    //stores the highest allowed random number

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* oldRands;
    //stores the previously generated numbers
```

`uniqueRandom` returns a unique random number between 1 and self.maxRand each time. If all allowable numbers have been returned it returns 0.

```
- (int) uniqueRandom {
    int result = 0;
    if ([self.oldRands count] != self.maxRand) {
        int randomValue =  (arc4random() %  self.maxRand )+ 1;
        NSNumber* boxedValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:randomValue];
        if ([self.oldRands indexOfObject:boxedValue]==NSNotFound) {
            [self.oldRands addObject: boxedValue];
            result = randomValue;
        } else {
             result = [self uniqueRandom];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You should consider that it doesn't make sense to change self.maxRand once it is initialised unless you also reset self.oldRands. So you might want to use a `const` or `#define` instead, and/or tie it in to your `self.oldRands` initialiser.

Comment: I've tryed but It doesn't work! The questions are still repeating :(

Comment: @AlessandroBava, you have a couple of other issues, see my updated answer

Comment: Thank You for your help! You're in right with the kk, and I've made a property. for the j I was confused with other codes where the first index is 1. Thank You to notice that. I've understood what you've said in point 3, but I don't know how to implement a new random value and then how to check it.

Comment: @AlessandroBava, see my next update with a few more suggestions

Comment: but he compact function is not a void funtion? how about a complete script that's working? sorry but I'm trying to mesh all these hints but nothing is stil working...

Comment: it was a void function because I thought it was the _list_ of unique randoms you were interested in, stored in self.oldquest. I've added a new update method (complete) that returns a unique random int.

Comment: why my app crashes when I add this code? How can i give to you my project to see it? Thank You

Comment: @AlessandroBava, you could post a link to your project in the question. Better though, accept my answer  (as we have strayed quite far from your original post, and in your question there is not enough context to answer everything). Start a new question showing your current code. If it is crashing, show the crash error. Perhaps try some logging first to see where it is unhappy.